# Replication Behavior in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a single mongod instance with 2 replications(secondary mongod instances) and a java code which inserts 1 million simple objects with WriteConcern = JOURNAL_SAFE.
While the java code is in execution we kill the primary instance, the java code throws an exception server not available. Then i shutdown both other secondary nodes and started each node separately as standalone and then check the record count. we observe that record count in both secondary mongod instances is same while in primary a one record is missing and the missing record is the one on which the job failed(mongod instance was killed).
Can anyone please explain this behavior, if the record is not present is primary how can it be possible that record exist in secondary.

Regards,
Bhagwant Bhobe

Answer (score 2):

This not at all unexpected  - in fact, I would expect this to be the case because replication in MongoDB is asynchronous and "as fast as possible" - as soon as the primary records the write in memory, it is visible via the oplog to the secondaries which apply it to themselves.

Because you killed the primary server before it had a chance to flush the write from memory to disk, that node does not have the inserted record when you examine it, but the secondaries have it because it was replicated, and normally replication takes less time than flushing data to disk (though it depends on speed of your disk, speed of your network and relative timing of events).

Comment: but i have enabled journal option, So whenever i start my primary node again, it should have recovered that loss data which is present with secondary node.

Comment: And also when the users see that the java code failed on which record, he will try to insert that record again,but that record is already in mongodb.

Comment: @Asya this should not happen. MongoDB first should save new record on primary server and later on [Oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). If the new document is not present on primary server, it should not be replicated.

Comment: you can argue that MongoDB storage and replication *should* work differently (some would disagree) but the way I described is the way it actually works.  And @BhagwantBhobe you should use replica_acknowledged instead of journal_safe - that way if the primary fails and the secondary takes over the data that's been acknowledged is guaranteed to be there.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky : I have a java code which inserts document object first in mongoDB and then in a text file, the record on which the java code throws an error(Since primary node is down) that record is present in secondary node,So from user point of view that records which returned error should never be in the mongoDB

Comment: Well, it's not in the primary that you crashed, right?  So that matches your expectations.   Since you are using writeConcern that only cares about local to primary, I don't understand why this doesn't match your expectations.   You should probably adjust the logic in your Java code if this sequence of events is problematic.